# Shell commands as root

Tags: java, shell

I was trying to execute `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /PID ... /F");`, but I keep getting permission denied on error stream. I know it normally requires opening cmd as root, but I was wondering if there's a way to achieve that with code (something in Windows like adding sudo in the beginning).

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you to use the runas functionality in Windows.

> Runas allows a user to run specific tools and programs with different
> permissions than the user's current logon provides.

Please try something like:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c \"runas /savecred /user:theDomain\\administrator yourCommand\"")
```

[Runas Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/cc771525(v=ws.11))

Comment: Hello, did you have a moment to check my reply? If it was useful for you please consider upvoting it and / or choosing it as final answer. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You can open CMD with administrator privileges and run your Java program with Administrator privileges too. When invoking to shell it should inherit those permissions and be able to exec with Administrator privileges.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. :)